# Alpha Beta Pruning Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I'm working on a project for my AI class and we are required to implement depth-bounded minimax search and then add alpha-beta pruning on a game of Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe, or Tic-Tac-Toe-Ception. This version of tic-tac-toe is a 3x3 game board of 3x3 game boards. When you play in a space on the smallBoards, the move you just played corresponds to the next smallBoard the opponent will be playing on. I have been able to find results for regular tic tac toe, but they don't quite apply because of the rules of the game.

If you play in the center of the top left board, the next player will play in the center board of the bigBoard. A picture of these two moves is provided. Red being the first player.

[Here's the picture of the first two moves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/993zr.jpg)

**Our trouble is with our alpha-beta implemetation.**

***Regarding our Depth-Bounded Minimax Search***

Our minimax implementation appears to be working correctly. When we attempted to implement alpha-beta our AI agent stopped function correctly.

Our minimax implementation code is as follows:

```
function evaluateMove(outerX2, outerY2, innerX2, innerY2, depth, isAI, tempBoard)
{
var currentBoard = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( tempBoard ));
var score = 0;
var bestScore = 0;

var playerZZ;
if (isAI) {
    playerZZ = 2;
}
else {
    playerZZ = 1;
}
if(checkForWin(2, JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( currentBoard )), outerX2, outerY2, innerX2, innerY2))
{
    //AI wins
    return 10;
}
if(checkForWin(1, JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( currentBoard )), outerX2, outerY2, innerX2, innerY2))
{
    //Human wins
    return -10;
}
else if (depth == 2) {
    return 0;
}
if (checkForBoardWin(innerX2, innerY2, 1) || checkForBoardWin(innerX2, innerY2, 2))
{
    if (isAI)
    {
    bestScore = -100;
        for (var X = 0; X < 3; X++)
        {
            for (var Y = 0; Y < 3; Y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                {
                    for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                    {
                        if(currentBoard[X][Y][x][y] == 0 && !(checkForBoardWin(X, Y, 1) || checkForBoardWin(X, Y, 2)))
                        {
                            //JAKE: Broken here?
                            currentBoard[X][Y][x][y] = 2
                            score = evaluateMove(X, Y, x, y, depth + 1, false, currentBoard);
                            //var bestScore = -100;
                            if (score > bestScore)
                            {
                                console.log("Line 105: Score = ", score);
                                return score;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return bestScore;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
    bestScore = 100;
        for (var X = 0; X < 3; X++)
        {
            for (var Y = 0; Y < 3; Y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                {
                    for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                    {
                        if(currentBoard[X][Y][x][y] == 0)
                        {
                            currentBoard[X][Y][x][y] = 1
                            score = evaluateMove(X, Y, x, y, depth + 1, false, currentBoard);
                            //bestScore = 100;
                            if (score < bestScore)
                            {
                                console.log("Line 137: Score = ", score);
                                return score;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return bestScore;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
bestScore = -100;
    if (isAI)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                if(currentBoard[innerX2][innerY2][x][y] == 0)
                {
                    //JAKE: Broken here?
                    currentBoard[innerX2][innerY2][x][y] = 2
                    score = evaluateMove(innerX2, innerY2, x, y, depth + 1, false, currentBoard);
                    //bestScore = -100;
                    if (score > bestScore)
                    {
                        console.log("Line 169: Score = ", score);
                        return score;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return bestScore;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
    bestScore = 100;
        for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                if(currentBoard[innerX2][innerY2][x][y] == 0)
                {
                    currentBoard[innerX2][innerY2][x][y] = 1
                    score = evaluateMove(innerX2, innerY2, x, y, depth + 1, true, currentBoard);
                    bestScore = 100;
                    if (score < bestScore)
                    {
                        console.log("Line 195: Score = ", score);
                        return score;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return bestScore;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

***Regarding our Alpha-Beta Pruning implementation:***

Our evaluate move function takes in a few variables, both X2's and Y2's make up the Four Dimensional array coordinates of the move in the bigBoard we are now evaluating. We followed the pseudo code from [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning#Pseudocode). Unfortunately our AI plays the the top left corner until it has no more option to do so, in which case it plays down the left side of the board. My group and I have been pulling our hair out over this for the past few days.

The code is as follows.

```
function evaluateMove(outerX2, outerY2, innerX2, innerY2, depth, isAI, tempBoard)
{
var currentBoard = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( tempBoard ));
var score = 0;
var bestScore = 0;

var playerZZ;
if (isAI) {
    playerZZ = 2;
}
else {
    playerZZ = 1;
}
if(checkForWin(2, JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( currentBoard )), outerX2, outerY2, innerX2, innerY2))
{
    //AI wins
    return 10;
}
if(checkForWin(1, JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( currentBoard )), outerX2, outerY2, innerX2, innerY2))
{
    //Human wins
    return -10;
}
else if (depth == 2) {
    return 0;
}
if (checkForBoardWin(innerX2, innerY2, 1) || checkForBoardWin(innerX2, innerY2, 2))
{
    if (isAI)
    {
    bestScore = -100;
        for (var X = 0; X < 3; X++)
        {
            for (var Y = 0; Y < 3; Y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                {
                    for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                    {
                        if(currentBoard[X][Y][x][y] == 0 && !(checkForBoardWin(X, Y, 1) || checkForBoardWin(X, Y, 2)))
                        {
                            //JAKE: Broken here?
                            currentBoard[X][Y][x][y] = 2
                            score = evaluateMove(X, Y, x, y, depth + 1, false, currentBoard);
                            //var bestScore = -100;
                            if (score > bestScore)
                            {
                                console.log("Line 105: Score = ", score);
                                return score;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return bestScore;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
    bestScore = 100;
        for (var X = 0; X < 3; X++)
        {
            for (var Y = 0; Y < 3; Y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                {
                    for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                    {
                        if(currentBoard[X][Y][x][y] == 0)
                        {
                            currentBoard[X][Y][x][y] = 1
                            score = evaluateMove(X, Y, x, y, depth + 1, false, currentBoard);
                            //bestScore = 100;
                            if (score < bestScore)
                            {
                                console.log("Line 137: Score = ", score);
                                return score;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return bestScore;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
bestScore = -100;
    if (isAI)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                if(currentBoard[innerX2][innerY2][x][y] == 0)
                {
                    //JAKE: Broken here?
                    currentBoard[innerX2][innerY2][x][y] = 2
                    score = evaluateMove(innerX2, innerY2, x, y, depth + 1, false, currentBoard);
                    //bestScore = -100;
                    if (score > bestScore)
                    {
                        console.log("Line 169: Score = ", score);
                        return score;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return bestScore;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
    bestScore = 100;
        for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                if(currentBoard[innerX2][innerY2][x][y] == 0)
                {
                    currentBoard[innerX2][innerY2][x][y] = 1
                    score = evaluateMove(innerX2, innerY2, x, y, depth + 1, true, currentBoard);
                    bestScore = 100;
                    if (score < bestScore)
                    {
                        console.log("Line 195: Score = ", score);
                        return score;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return bestScore;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```